# Sketch App - changing orientation point for position of object

Tags: sketch-app

In Sketch App, For the X and Y position of an object, is there a way to configure it to display the X and Y of a different corner of the object?

[image]

It seems to always display the X and Y of the top-left. But I'm interested to know the X and Y of the bottom-left or bottom-right or top-right. Illustrator had a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nope :(

The closest feature would be moving the rotation center while in Rotate mode.

[image: GIF of moving the rotation center for selected layer in Sketch 3]